# Change backslash to slash in PHP

Tags: php, database, str-replace, backslash, unlink

I have a database that opens images that I have in a folder. I can delete the entry from the database but not the image. The path of the image in the database contains backslash, but the path of the folder to be deleted has slash. I need to change the backslash to slash.

The database path is: fotos\mural\foto.jpg

The folder I want to delete is: ../../fotos/mural/foto.jpg

This is my scripy that does NOT work.

```
<?php
$v1 = $_GET['identifica'];
            $link = mysqli_connect("x.mysql.db", "x", "x");
            $database = mysqli_select_db($link, "xbecedqkxbisbe");   
            mysqli_set_charset( $link, "utf8");           
            $string = "SELECT * FROM mural WHERE id= $v1";
            $resultat = mysqli_query($link, $string);    
            while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultat)) { 
                $borra = $fila['Fotomural'];
                $direc = '(..\..\)';
                $ara = "'$direc''$borra'";
                unlink($ara);
        }   
            $query = "delete from mural where id = '$v1'";
            mysqli_query($link, $query);        
    ?>
```

Comment: Right off the bat, one thing I see is that both these paths are different.

Comment: please show us your code.

Comment: $v1 = $_GET['identifica'];
$link = mysqli_connect("xbecedqkxbisbe.mysql.db", "xbecedqkxbisbe", "Certascan55");
   $database = mysqli_select_db($link, "xbecedqkxbisbe");   
   mysqli_set_charset( $link, "utf8");           
      $string = "SELECT * FROM mural WHERE id= $v1";
   $resultat = mysqli_query($link, $string);    
   while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultat)) { 
    $borra = $fila['Fotomural'];
    $direc = '(..\..\)';
    $ara = "'$direc''$borra'";
    unlink($ara);
  } 
      $query = "delete from mural where id = '$v1'";
      mysqli_query($link, $query);

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the relevant code there instead of in the comments, thx

Comment: You already tagged this with `str-replace`, does that now work?

Comment: what you get in  `$ara`

Comment: This not work:
$borr = str_replace( '\', '/', $borra );

Comment: you have use these 2 different paths `fotos \ mural \ foto.jpg` and `../../fotos/mural/foto.jpg`

Comment: where you use in code `str_replace`

Comment: 105/5000
I need to add the directory change. 
The path image\\photo.jpg cannot be changed by image/photo.jpg

Comment: what you get in  `$borra = $fila['Fotomural'];`

Comment: `$file = '../../'.str_replace('\\', '/', $file)`

Comment: $prost = str_replace ('\', '/', $prova);
I have done separate tests

Answer (score 0):

You are wrapping these variables inside single quotes while concatenating.

```
$ara = "'$direc''$borra'";
```

Instead do this:

```
$Ara = "$direc$borra";
```